# Как решить проблему с выводом переменной из контроллера в вид?

Tags: laravel

Добрый день господа.
Проблема следующего характера.
**Имеется контроллер и 2 переменные в нем. 
Пытаюсь данные переменные вывести в index.blade.php.
Но дэбагер мне говорит что их нету.**

Некоторые люди на стороннем форуме опирались на кеш, в барузере я его почистил, но ошибка тоже такая же :(

[Ссылка на код](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e20017e2d20a67f4446c104d551ecb24)

Comment: По какой ссылке страницу запрашиваете?

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Comment: http://univer-larave.ru/laravel/public/

Comment: Ну и? А на контроллер какой маршрут прописан?

Comment: Route::get('/','IndexController@index');
Если Вас правильно понял, указал так теперь. Ошибка та же самая.                   ErrorException in 6daadb9387ee157e44a58ed3ac57ecf24d382821.php line 64:
Undefined variable: namesite (View: D:\Program\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\univer-larave.ru\laravel\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: А все :) Понял, пасибоооооо

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

Пример передачи данных из контроллера в вид (view)

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $row = Customer::select('balance')->find(Auth::user()->id);

    return view('balance', [
      'balance' => $row->balance,
      'paypal_url' => $this->paypal_url 
    ]);
}
```